# (Spyder) IPython console: How can a (file-)link be printed

Tags: python, html, hyperlink, console, spyder

what I need is a way to print text to a (Spyder) IPython console that acts as a link and can be clicked, e.g.

```
print( link="http://google.de", text="google" )
print( link="C:/dev/myfile.py", text="myfile" )
print( link="C:/dev/myfile.py", line = 501 text="myfile:501" )
```

This helps a lot for debugging if you want to navigate quickly to the right line and file.

Best, 
SH

Comment: does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder developer here*) My answer:

1. This is not possible right now, and I doubt we will implement it in the future.
2. The Python console is going to be removed in Spyder **3.2**. So please start using the IPython console instead.

Comment: I edited the question -- is there a way to do it on the IPython console?